# How to use java.util.stream.Stream in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, java-stream

```
(import java.nio.file.Files)
(import java.nio.file.Paths)
(import java.util.stream.Stream)

(def path 
  (Paths/get "." 
    (into-array ["data" "10000000.test.log"])))

(def stream 
  (Files/lines path))
```

This way I have:

```
stream
#object[java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head 0x50129b8f
"java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@50129b8f"]
```

Is there a way to iterate over this without running out of memory? The suggestion on SO are not really helpful. The files is ~1G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to iterate over the stream Java / imperative style to avoid blowing up the heap. I do not need to reduce on the stream, I need to process every line and take out one field and send it out. I think for this I probably better off with doseq.

```
(doseq 
  [l (iterator-seq (.iterator stream))] 
    (println l))
```

Answer (score 6):

Do the same thing you would do in java. Call interop methods on it, like `(.map stream ...)`, or whatever else, and collect it to a list at the end, or reduce it, or whatever you need to do.

Clojure functions don't implement the interfaces that a stream expects, such as java.util.function.Function, so you'll need to use reify instead of a simple `fn`:

```
(.map stream (reify java.util.function.Function (apply [this x] (foo x))))
```

Comment: Not sure how this supposed to work. (def test (.map stream (reify java.util.function.Function (apply [this x] (println x))))) (take 1 test) Error printing return value (IllegalArgumentException) at clojure.lang.RT/seqFrom (RT.java:557).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3

Comment: A java stream is not a clojure sequence, and so you can't call clojure sequence functions on it. This is as true of `(.map stream f)` as it is of just `stream`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into a library called [ike.cljj](https://github.com/ajoberstar/ike.cljj) for some interop niceties.